# Django, deploy to heroku with uvicorn

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, uvicorn, asgi

I have a Django app that is deployed to  Heroku with daphne.

I would like to replace daphne with uvicorn, so I changed my Procfile to the following:

```
web: bin/start-pgbouncer uvicorn rivendell.asgi:application --limit-max-requests=1200 --port $PORT
worker: python manage.py runworker channel_layer -v2
```

But the server started and crashed almost immediately with the following error:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the host to listen to `0.0.0.0` next time via:

```
--host 0.0.0.0
```